# How to compile python program ( convert to pyc) in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, compilation

There are two ways to generate pyc in python2:

1.

```
import py_compile
py_compile.compile("file.py")
```

2.

`python -m compileall ./`

How to do it python3? I tried both of the above approaches, both are not generating .pyc file in python3. Please help.

Comment: the `python -m compileall ./` should be working for both python 2 and 3, It works for me, I have python 3

Comment: iirc: in Python3 the .pyc files are stored in __pycache directories instead of the same path as the script file. So even if the pyc file is generated you wont see it in the usual place.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @meissner_

1. `import py_compile`

   `py_compile.compile("file.py") #compiles single file named file.py`
2. `python -m compileall ./ #combines all programs under current directory`

Both approaches work in Python2 and Python3. Only difference in Python2 and Python3 is:

1. **Python2** generates .pyc file in the **same directory** whereas
2. **Python3** creates it in a folder named **__pycache__** inside the same directory.